# Trying to run this code in MIPS and i am getting an error saying "Runtime exception at 0x00400090: address out of range 0x00000008"

Tags: range, mips, outofrangeexception

```
.text
main: #Main function to be run
la $a0, prompt

li $v0, 4
syscall


la $a0, n0


li $a1, 8

li $v0, 8
syscall
move $t0, $v0

la $a0, n1
li $a1, 8
li $v0, 8
syscall
move $t1, $v0

la $a0, n2
li $a1, 8
li $v0, 8
syscall
move $t2, $v0

la $a0, n3

li $a1, 8

li $v0, 8
syscall
move $t3, $v0


la $a0, n4

li $a1, 8

li $v0, 8
syscall
move $t4, $v0

#Outputs
la $a0, ($t0)

li $v0, 8
syscall

la $a0, ($t1)

li $v0, 8
syscall

la $a0, ($t2)

li $v0, 8
syscall

la $a0, ($t3)

li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, ($t4)

li $v0, 4
syscall



li $v0, 10
syscall




.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a series of 5 formulae:\n" #The prompt to ask the user to type 5 strings
n0: .space 20
n1: .space 20
n2: .space 20
n3: .space 20
n4: .space 20
```

Comment: Without reading the code, if you are getting that error message, it generally means you have accidentally add "8" to NULL and tried to read memory.  Check  to make sure your base pointer is correct and not 0 before the add of 8.  The first value 0x00400090 probably means the error is 0x90 bytes from the top of the file.  Finally, do you need a return at the end of your function so that it doesn't fall into the data area?

Comment: `la $a0,(t1)` is a weird instruction. The assembler will turn that into `addi $a0, $t1, 0`, which is to say to make a copy of `$t1` into `$a0`.

Comment: Apologies for not adding comments. i want t0...t4 to store input values and then print them out consecutively at the end

Comment: System call 8 doesn't return anything. Also, you're using the wrong system call number in a few places in the "Outputs" part (using number 8 when you should be using 4).

Comment: Thanks @Michael i made the changes, still getting the error. Im not sure if my temporary registers are actually storing the input values

Comment: They do not. Because, like I said, system call 8 doesn't return anything. Consult the system call documentation for the simulator you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what to do:

Find out what line of your assembly code corresponds to `0x00400090` — or the address of the exception.  That is the specific instruction that is getting the fault.  Then look for inputs to that instruction that are incorrect (i.e. here, that have value `0x00000008`, and fix the code so that register has a proper address).

You can do this in the MARS simulator.  When it reports the exception, have a look at the excepting instruction, and check the register values at that point.  If you want you can also set a breakpoint on or just before the excepting instruction, and re-run it so you can see the register state as it evolves prior to the exception.